# Image of unit ball under twice differentiable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(x) = 0$ outside of the unit ball $B \in \mathbb{R^n}$. I have to show that (the measure is Lebesgue): $$\int_B \det Df = 0$$

I tried to prove that $|f(B)| = 0$ (which should be equivalent to the above) but I've had no luck. I'm quite stuck since I have no further theorem that I can think of, and honestly the equality doesn't even intuitively seem to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. Consider the form
$$
w=f_1df_2\wedge\ldots \wedge df_n-f_2df_1\wedge df_3\ldots \wedge df_n+\ldots+(-1)^nf_ndf_1\wedge \ldots \wedge df_{n-1}
$$
and apply the Stokes theorem:
$$
\int_{\partial B}w=\int_{B}dw.
$$

Comment: I don't quite get it. $d\omega = ndf$ I see it is related to the determinant but I don't understand why. And also I don't know how to compute the boundary of $B$, since I don't have any suitable parametrisation.

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga ${\mathrm d}w=n{\mathrm d}f_1\wedge\ldots\wedge {\mathrm d}f_n=n \det (\partial_jf_i){\mathrm d}x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge {\mathrm d}x_n$. It's standard material, ${\mathrm d}f_i=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_jf_i{\mathrm d}x_j$ and the wedge product gives the determinant. 

No need for parametrisation since $f_i|_{\partial B}=0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, so $w|_{\partial B}=0$.